# How do you enable Azure Key Vault logging using Terraform 11.14?

Tags: logging, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

How do you enable Azure Key Vault logging using Terraform 11.14?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could refer to [this example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_diagnostic_setting) to enable diagnostic_setting for existing Azure Key vault.

For example, this works for me. I am using Terraform `v0.12.5` + provider.azurerm `v1.32.0`

**EDIT**: You do not need to quote the identifiers in `v0.12+` as there are no functions present, i.e. `data.azurerm_key_vault.test.id` vs `"${data.azurerm_key_vault.test.id}"`

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "test"{
    name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "test" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}

data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "test" {
  name                = "myloganalytics"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "test" {
  name                = "mystorageaccountname"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "test" {
  name               = "example"
  target_resource_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.test.id}"
  storage_account_id = "${data.azurerm_storage_account.test.id}"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = "${data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.test.id}"


  log {
    category = "AuditEvent"
    enabled  = false

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "diagnostic-log-analytic" {
  name               = "diagnostic-setting"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.<Your KeyVault>.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.<Your Log Analytics WS>.id

  log {
    category = "AuditEvent"
    enabled  = true
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"
    enabled = true
  }
}
```